# How do i fix an <input type='radio'> where i select one and the others unselect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Im relative new to Vue/Nuxt. I'm debugging a group of inputs type=radio that will not unselect when I select another option. I believe I have isolated the issue to this piece of code shown below. I'm trying to make sense of the code written by the other developer, especially the v-model= $store.state.currentModefiers. How do I go about fixing this bug that will not unselect the other options when I select a different

[image]

```js
<div
                  v-for="(modifier, index) in getMenuModifiers(
                    groupModifiers._id
                  )"
                  :key="'MMi' + index"
                >
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    :id="index"
                    :ref="modifier._id"
                    :value="modifier"
                    @change="check($event)"
                    v-model="$store.state.currentModifiers"
                  />
                  <label :for="modifier._id">{{ modifier.title }}</label>
                </div>
```

Comment: It good practice to use code instead of images

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that `v-model` serves as the model and links the various radio-button that share the same value for this attribute.

You should check if the value you've used is the same among those radio-buttons you want to be in the same group.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#sauceChoice', data: {sauce: ''}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="sauceChoice" class="demo">
  <h3>Salad Sauce</h3>
  <input type="radio" v-model="sauce" value="Blue Cheese">Blue Cheese<br>
  <input type="radio" v-model="sauce" value="Sweet Curry Mustard">Sweet Curry Mustard<br>
  <input type="radio" v-model="sauce" value="Ranch">Ranch<br>
  <br>
  <p>value: {{sauce}}</p>
</div>
```

Source: [Vue.js > Form input Bindings > Basic Usage > Radio](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio)